# Spark distribute task imbalanced (doesn't respect to repartition number)

Tags: python, apache-spark, memory, memory-management, pyspark

I want to reduce memory usage on each task. So I use repartition to scale down the job size .

## Prepare Data

```py
group_cols = ['product_id', 'city_zip']
partition_number=8000

df = read_features(spark, start_time, end_time, input_path=input_path, group_cols=group_cols)

df = df.agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.struct(*data_cols)
    ).alias('data')
)

if group_min_size:
    group_min_size = int(group_min_size)
    df = df.filter(F.size('data') >= group_min_size)


# ---! repartition here !

df = df.repartition(partition_number, *group_cols) 
df = df.groupBy(*group_cols)



sp = spark.read.parquet(TB.STORE_PRODUCT)
sp.cache()
total = sp.dropDuplicates(['product_code', 'city_zip']).count()

# --- total groups !

print(total)
# 22536

df = df.join(
    store_product,
    on=[*group_cols],
    how='inner'
)
```

## Map reduce

```
pipe = AutoARIMAPipe(....)  # simple wrap of pmdarima

# train a model for each group
df1 = (df.rdd
      .map(lambda r: r.asDict())
      .map(lambda d: pipe.transform_data(d))
      .map(lambda d: pipe.create_model(d))
      .map(lambda d: pipe.fit(d))
      .filter(lambda d: d.get('model') is not None )  # 
      .map(lambda d: pipe.pickle_model(d))
)
```

## What I expect

1. `df.rdd.map` would split total (group total number is 22536)  to 8000 parts .
2. So only 2 to 3 groups (22536/8000 = 2.817) for each task . Spark should evenly distribute group by repartition number

But it doesn't .

## There are many failed in my task

There are a lot of memory error:

```
ExecutorLostFailure (executor 8 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 8.0 GB of 8 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or disabling yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled because of YARN-4714.
```

[image]

This is the excact reason I set `partition_number=8000` in order to reduce memory usage on each node .

Then I check a task's log, you can see there are much more groups than 3 were distributed to this task . Why ??

[image]

How do I achieve my aim to reduce each task memory usage to prevent OOM on spark executor nodes ?

Comment: how you are running your code? spark-submit or spark-shell? can you share the command you ran for depoying this driver script?

Comment: @smart_coder spark-submit .  There is nothing special, in order to keep simple I omit many parameters in code . What do you want to know from command? It's running on Yarn, with some resource setting.  For my view, it's no relation to command ,  problem are group distribution is wrong and I want to fix it .